# How to invoke exe from the gradle task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I need to invoke the build.exe file from the gradle task. I have tried the following option but it always results in the Build Failure with the following reason.

```
task buildIA() {
  doFirst {
    println "Executing Install Anywhere Build"
  }
  doLast {
    exec {
      executable 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\InstallAnywhere 2018\\build.exe'
      args (['C:\\Users\\test.iap_xml', '+lv', '+wv'])
    }
  }
}
```

**output:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildIA'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallAnywhere 2018\build.exe''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Note: If I manually run `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\InstallAnywhere 2018\\build.exe" C:\\Users\\test.iap_xml +lv +wv` from command prompt it is working fine.

**StackTrace:** Below is the stacktrace.
gradlew.bat buildIA --stacktrace

```
> Task :buildIA FAILED
Executing Install Anywhere Build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildIA'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallAnywhere 2018\build.exe''

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':buildIA'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallAnywhere 2018\build.exe''
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:237)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:214)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:364)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:87)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallAnywhere 2018\build.exe'
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:98)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:71)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallAnywhere 2018\build.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\nc665504\git\PAM-SC-MigrationUtility\SAMDataExtraction"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
        ... 9 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (equal sign added after executable and args):

```
task buildIA() {
  doFirst {
    println "Executing Install Anywhere Build"
  }
  doLast {
    exec {
      executable = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\InstallAnywhere 2018\\build.exe'
      args = ['C:\\Users\\test.iap_xml', '+lv', '+wv']
    }
  }
}
```

Another option is to use a `commandLine` like this

```
task buildIA() {
  doFirst {
    println "Executing Install Anywhere Build"
  }
  doLast {
    exec {
        commandLine "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\InstallAnywhere 2018\\build.exe", "C:\\Users\\test.iap_xml", "+lv", "+wv"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried but the same result. `Execution failed for task ':buildIA'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallAnywhere 2018\build.exe''`

Comment: I tried your code with a notepad++ executable on my env (gradle 7.0) and it didn't work, and this was fixed by adding =. Which version of gradle do you use?

Comment: You can also try a commandLine, from my last edit

Comment: Used commandLine also but the result is same.

Comment: That's strange, try running your task like this 'gradle buildIA --stacktrace' and show the results

Comment: Added the stacktrace.

Comment: Here is the cause 'CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation', you lack the required permissions to run this command

Comment: I have already given full permission to build.exe.

Comment: Even I have tried running the gradle task from the command prompt with the admin privilege resulted the same error.